# Check for a string with line break in a column using java drools

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the below data in a table -

```
ID    ABC_23_02
--    --------
01    See your note and security instrument for information about 
      -what happens if you fail to make your payments,
      -what is a default on the loan.
```

Now, I want to trigger a rule when the same value is found in the column. Here is my code snippet -

```
rule "Rule - Success"
    when
        form: Form_ABC()
        $m: Map()
        $ID: Object() from $m["ID"]
        $x: Object() from $m["ABC_23_02"]
        Map(Utility.rtnString($x) == "See your note and security instrument for information about\n-what happens if you fail to make your payments,\n-what is a default on the loan.") 
    then
        Utility.helper(drools);
        if(!($ID.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ID")))
        {
        form.setCD_23_02(Utility.rtnString($x));
        System.out.println("Rule - Pass\t\t" + $ID.toString() 
                                             + "\tField 1 is: " + $x.toString());
        }
end
```

And, here is the Utility.rtnString($x) function that i am calling -

```
public static String rtnString(Object Input)  {
            //String numOnly = Input.toString().replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\.]","");
            String numOnly = Input.toString().replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\.\n]","");
            return numOnly.toUpperCase();
        }
```

But, I am not able to look for the string in the column using the above. Can you please suggest a better way to achieve the same. Thanks.

Comment: Is this related to JavaScript?

Comment: No, this is a simple java code to just trigger a scenario where we are reading data from an csv file.

Comment: I was asking because it has the `JavaScript` tag.